# LWC platform events timing out?

Tags: lightning-web-components, platform-event

So I have 2 LWC components, one which publishes a platform event (a text message from an input box) and another one which listens to it and then resposnds by publishing a platform event of its own. When I open the publisher and the receiver components in different tabs to test the communication, everything works fine.

The issue is, that after a while, I guess after 5 minutes or so, If i try to publish another message from the first component, it is not received at the receiver. My gut is that the listening connection is being terminated by the server as said [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/using_streaming_api_timeouts.htm).

If so, can someone please tell me how to keep the platform event susbcription alive from an LWC component?

Comment: Is this in your developer org or your sandbox org in company?

Comment: @NagendraSingh I tried it in both, a sandbox and also my personal dev box. Its the same behaviour.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, Did you find any additional information about it ?

Comment: Nope. This still happens. Only way is to refresh the page.